# User input validation with Relay

Tags: graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

From the looks of it, it seems that the best way to do validation with Relay is to use [custom GraphQL scalar types](https://github.com/mugli/learning-graphql/blob/master/7.%20Deep%20Dive%20into%20GraphQL%20Type%20System.md#bonus-creating-custom-scalar-types) in your schema. Is this so?

Comment: It would be great to have support for client-side validation using custom scalar types. But I suppose that is not an option right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think of this as being analogous to server-side type validation with a REST API.

While you can validate scalar data that way, this code runs on the server rather than the client, and it's equivalent to e.g. a REST backend rejecting a request with a 400.

In practice, for ideal UX, you probably want to do some of this validation on the client side to offer more feedback (and more immediate feedback) when practical.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing client-side validation of course. But I want server-side validation too. On the front-end I am using Joi via the `react-validation` component. So should I validate payloads in my root resolve methods in this same way?

Comment: You can definitely do additional validation in your mutation resolver. I don't see where else you could do schema-level validation, for example. Effectively doing validation with custom scalar types is totally fine too.